# Is using Tor illegal in India?

Tags: legal

Though I most often do not require reason to use Tor, I do sometimes out of curiosity.

So, my question is, is there any legal statute in India that can land me into legal hassles because of using Tor, even when I'm doing perfectly legal activities, like browsing, texting, checking emails, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the broader question concerns encryption in India in general, rather than Tor specifically.

Looking at similar questions on other SE boards, the short answer seems to be: "*it's not illegal to use encryption technologies, but if you're asked to decrypt your own data, and you refuse, you could get into trouble*".

The following threads help flesh out the detail:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12281/encryption-laws-in-india-is-it-allowed-to-use-ssh-and-vpn
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92389/encryption-laws-in-india

For reference, this site might also be useful: http://www.cryptolaw.org/
There's a specific entry for India, [here](http://www.cryptolaw.org/cls2.htm#in).

The assumption in the above is, of course, that Tor and other anonymization software fall into the same category as regular encryption technologies.

Comment: Thanks very much, Richard! That really helped, the CryptoLaw website had a wonderful summary.